# Problem with \textbf and \textsc using mathdesign

Tags: fonts, mathdesign

As soon as I use the package `mathdesign` the commands `\textbf` and `\textsc` won't work for Sans Serif and Typewriter fonts. My MWE looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ugm} % URW Garamond
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop} % URW Classico (Optima)
\usepackage{luximono}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\normalfont RM-Family: Standard, emph, textbf, textit, textsl, texttt, textsc\\
\rmfamily Text, \emph{Text}, \textbf{Text}, \textit{Text}, \textsl{Text}, \texttt{Text}, "`Not available"'\\

\noindent
\normalfont SF-Family: Standard, emph, textbf, textit, textsl, texttt, textsc\\
\sffamily Text, \emph{Text}, \textbf{Text}, \textit{Text}, \textsl{Text}, \texttt{Text}, \textsc{Text}\\

\noindent
\normalfont TT-Family: Standard, emph, textbf, textit, textsl, texttt, textsc\\
\ttfamily Text, \emph{Text}, \textbf{Text}, \textit{Text}, \textsl{Text}, \texttt{Text}, "`Not available"'

\end{document}
```

It leads to 3 Warnings which are all similar to this one:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/uop/mb/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/uop/m/n' instead on input line 19.
```

My output looks like this (I marked the spots responsible for the warnings):

[image: Example with problems]

If I use `{\fontseries{b}\selectfont Text}` instead of `\textbf{Text}` and `{\fontshape{sc}\selectfont Text}` instead of `\textsc{Text}`, everything works fine, I don't get any warning and my result looks like this:

[image: Example without problems]

Not changing the fonts in preamble for Sans Serif family and Typewriter (using the standard defined by the documentclass) won't solve the problem.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this? I'm working in the following environment: Miktex 2.9 (64-bit); [mathdesign 2.31](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign); Roman-font: [URW Garamond](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond); Sans Serif-font: [URW Classico](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico); Typewriter-font: [LuxiMono](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/LuxiMono).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out, that you can solve the problem by using [Garamondx](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/garamondx) as your font instead of Garamond. You can download and install it from CTAN. The MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ugm} % URW Garamond
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop} % URW Classico (Optima)
\usepackage{luximono}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\normalfont RM-Family: Standard, emph, textbf, textit, textsl, texttt, textsc\\
\rmfamily Text, \emph{Text}, \textbf{Text}, \textit{Text}, \textsl{Text}, \texttt{Text}, "`Not available"'\\

\noindent
\normalfont SF-Family: Standard, emph, textbf, textit, textsl, texttt, textsc\\
\sffamily Text, \emph{Text}, \textbf{Text}, \textit{Text}, \textsl{Text}, \texttt{Text}, \textsc{Text}\\

\noindent
\normalfont TT-Family: Standard, emph, textbf, textit, textsl, texttt, textsc\\
\ttfamily Text, \emph{Text}, \textbf{Text}, \textit{Text}, \textsl{Text}, \texttt{Text}, "`Not available"'

\end{document}
```

[image]